# how to resolve this choice conflict - JavaCC

Tags: grammar, parser-generator, operator-precedence, javacc

I have a javacc grammar that defines a simple scripting language with simple expressions and conditional statements that i am reviewing and trying to correct roughly defined like this :

```
void Statement() : {}
{
Assignment()
|
IfStatement()
}

void Assignment() : {}
{
  RealIdentifier() "=" SimpleExpression()
|
  StringIdentifier() "="  StringExpression()
}

void IfStatement() : {}
{
  "IF" Expression() "THEN" Block()
  (
    "ENDIF;"
  |
    "ELSE" Block() "ENDIF;"
  )
}
void Expression() #void : {}
{
  SimpleExpression()
  (
    "<" SimpleExpression() #LTNode(2)
  |
    ">" SimpleExpression() #GTNode(2)
  |
    "<=" SimpleExpression() #LENode(2)
  |
    ">=" SimpleExpression() #GENode(2)
  |
    "==" SimpleExpression() #EQNode(2) 
  |
    "!=" SimpleExpression() #NENode(2)
  )*
}

void SimpleExpression() #void : {}
{
  Term()
  (
    "+" Term()  #AddNode(2)
  |
    "-" Term()  #SubsNode(2)
  |
    "|" Term() #OrNode(2)
  )*
}

void Term() #void : {}
{
  Factor()
  ( 
    "*" Factor() #MultNode(2)
  |
    "/" Factor() #DivNode(2)
  |
    "&" Factor() #AndNode(2)
  )*
}

void Factor() #void : {}
{
  Real()
|
  RealIdentifier()
|
  Function()
|
  "(" Expression() ")"
|
  "!" Factor() #NotNode(1)
|
  StringExpression()
}

void Function() : 
{
  Token t;
  int args = 0;
}
{
t = <FUNCTION> { jjtThis.setID(t.image, legacyCharset); } "(" args = ArgumentList() ")"  
  { jjtThis.setArgs(args); }
}

int ArgumentList() #void : 
{
  int args = 0;
}
{
  Expression() {args++;} ( "," Expression() {args++;} )*
  { return args; }
}

void StringIdentifier() :
{
Token t;
}
{
t = <STRING_IDENTIFIER>
{
System.out.println("kind="+t.kind+" image="+t.image);
}
}

void RealIdentifier() : 
{
Token t;
}
{
t =  <REAL_IDENTIFIER>
{
System.out.println("kind="+t.kind+" image="+t.image);
}
}
```

The first obvious problem is in the way Expression is defined and since it is used to define the IfStatement, i can easily end up with something like this :
If (variable1 < variable2 >= variable3 )

I am trying to correct that by separating the logic of conditional expressions from that of expressions in general like this :

```
void IfStatement() : {}
{
  "IF" ConditionalExpression() "THEN" Block()
  (
    "ENDIF;"
  |
    "ELSE" Block() "ENDIF;"
  )
}
void ConditionalExpression() #void : {}
{
  SimpleExpression()
  (
    "<" #LTNode(2)
  |
    ">" #GTNode(2)
  |
    "<=" #LENode(2)
  |
    ">=" #GENode(2)
  |
    "==" #EQNode(2) 
  |
    "!=" #NENode(2)
  )SimpleExpression()
}
void Expression() #void : {}
( SimpleExpression() )*
}
```

when compiling the generated jj file i got the following warning :
Warning: Choice conflict in (...)* construct at line 210, column 3.
         Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct
         have common prefixes, one of which is: "+"
         Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion.

The error line number is for a line in the generated jj file.I assumed the conflict is when encoutering a SimpleExpression since it won't be able to figure out if what's being parsed is a ConditionalExpression or an Expression so i tried with :

```
void Expression() #void : {}
{
  ( LOOKAHEAD(2) SimpleExpression() )*
}
```

and then

```
void ConditionalExpression() #void : {}
{
( LOOKAHEAD(2)
  SimpleExpression()
  (
```

but it didn't go away. the line in the jj file where it says there's a choice conflict is

```
void Statement() : {/*@bgen(jjtree) Statement */
  ASTStatement jjtn000 = new ASTStatement(JJTSTATEMENT);
  boolean jjtc000 = true;
  jjtree.openNodeScope(jjtn000);
/*@egen*/} // <-------------------------------------- line 210
{/*@bgen(jjtree) Statement */
  try {
/*@egen*/
  Assignment()
|
```

the other problem is that operator precedence is somehow screwed up, something like
IF ( "a" == "a" | "c"=="c" )
results in the | being interpreted before the second == operator using the "c" as its second operand and that gives a ClassCastException, I concluded that fixing this would require a rewrite of the whole grammar, so i thought of maybe forcing parenthesis around single conditions of a composite conditional statement like this
if ( ("a" == "a") | ( "c" == "c" ) )
I am just unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You allow expressions to be completely empty?  Don't you want `( SimpleExpression() )+` for Expression?

Comment: you are right, in fact i posted some code i was experimenting with but that's not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the kleen-star, `*`, use `?` to make the right hand side (incl. the operator) of your relational expression optional so that a single `SimpleExpression()` would also match:

```
void Expression() #void : {}
{
  SimpleExpression()
  ( "<"  SimpleExpression() #LTNode(2)
  | ">"  SimpleExpression() #GTNode(2)
  | "<=" SimpleExpression() #LENode(2)
  | ">=" SimpleExpression() #GENode(2)
  | "==" SimpleExpression() #EQNode(2) 
  | "!=" SimpleExpression() #NENode(2)
  )?
}
```

This should not produce any conflicts, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem

> the other problem is that operator precedence is somehow screwed up, something like IF ( "a" == "a" | "c"=="c" ) results in the | being interpreted before the second == operator using the "c" as its second operand and that gives a ClassCastException,

Since you didn't post the grammar rules relevant to the `|` operator, it's hard to diagnose. The solution you propose should not be required.

I hope you don't mind a comment on the language design: Trying to enforce type correctness using the grammar is usually a poor choice.